# Flutter: PageView with dots Indicator in ListView does not work

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

Need to add in the *ListView* *PageView* with dots Indicator.
[image]

*PageView* will change background item *ListView*. **BUT** I get an error because height is not set statically, it depends on the amount of text inside item. [image]

p.s. *PageView* works well just in a container without *ListView*

I am attaching a test example of the code, where there is nothing superfluous, only *ListView*, *PageView* with dots Indicator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:worm_indicator/shape.dart';
import 'package:worm_indicator/worm_indicator.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  PageController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController();
  }

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int pos) {
        return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                colors: [const Color(0xFF3A1B9A), const Color(0xFF2196F3)],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              ),
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0));
      },
      itemCount: 3,
    );
  }

  Widget buildExampleIndicatorWithShapeAndBottomPos(Shape shape, double bottomPos) {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: bottomPos,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: WormIndicator(
        length: 3,
        controller: _controller,
        shape: shape,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[_buildListView(context)],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context) {
    final circleShape = Shape(
      size: 16,
      shape: DotShape.Circle,
      spacing: 8,
    );
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Card(
              elevation: 3.0,
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                buildPageView(),
                buildExampleIndicatorWithShapeAndBottomPos(circleShape, 20),
                Text('My text My text My text My text My text My text My text My text My text My text ')
              ]));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: code Please... I think wrapping the ```PageView``` with ```Container``` inside ```ListView``` will work.. ```ListView``` -- ```Container``` -- ```PageView```

Comment: @VinayHP I am attaching a test example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html). Just wrap your ListView and PageView inside a NestedScrollView, this widget should help handle nested viewports.